# indexOf não é reconhecido dentro do for

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, javascript-eventos, indexof

Olá estou tentando executar esse código para que capture todos os links de um pagina, funciona tudo ok, o problema esta que eu quero encontrar links que contem uma determinada palavra usando **indexOf** mas esta dando o seguinte erro no log..

```
Uncaught TypeError: str.IndexOf is not a function
at pesq (<anonymous>:22:14)
at <anonymous>:8:1
```

Alguma forma de resolver isso para que encontre apenas os links determinado indicado pelo **indexOf** ?

```
javascript: var w = window.open('', '', 'height=300, width=300');
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var b = a.length;

if(b != 0){ 
   w.document.write('<h1>Lista de Links </h1>'); 

for (i = 0; i < b; i++){ 

var str = a[i];

 if(str.indexOf('palavra')){
 w.document.write('<pre><a href=\'' + a[i] + '\'>' + a[i] + '</a>' + '</pre>');
}


}
}else{ 
    w.document.write('Nenhum link encontrado');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tem 2 problemas:

Voce está pegando o elemento ao inves do atributo href.

```
// Nesse caso, a[i] é um elemento do DOM
// var str = a[i];

// O correto seria:
var str = a[i].href
```

O metodo indexOf retorna -1 quando não encontra o caractere, logo todos links não iniciados com 'palavra' seriam exibidos

```
// Alternativa 1
if ( ~str.indexOf('palavra') ) 

// Alternativa 2
if ( str.indexOf('palavra') > -1 )
```

Veja seu código funcionando:

```
var janela = window.open( '', '', 'height=300, width=300' );
var elementos = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
var size = elementos.length;

if ( size ) {
  janela.document.write( '<h1>Lista de Links </h1>' );

  for ( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    var linkDoElemento = elementos[ i ].href;
    var textoDoElemento = elementos[ i ].textContent;
    if ( ~linkDoElemento.indexOf( 'stack' ) ) {
        janela.document.write( '<pre><a href=\'' + linkDoElemento + '\'>' + textoDoElemento.trim() + '</a>' + '</pre>' );
    }
  }
} else {
  janela.document.write( 'Nenhum link encontrado' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando usar `indexOf` em objetos colecionados em `getElementsByTagName`.

Se você quer verificar o texto em cada objeto, você pode usar `innerHTML` (irá verificar inclusive tags) ou `textContent` (apenas texto).

Acrescente `textContent` (ou `innerHTML` conforme for conveniente) aos `a[i]`:

```
javascript: var w = window.open('', '', 'height=300, width=300');
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var b = a.length;

if(b != 0){ 
   w.document.write('<h1>Lista de Links </h1>'); 
for (i = 0; i < b; i++){ 

var str = a[i].textContent;

 if(str.indexOf('palavra')){
 w.document.write('<pre><a href=\'' + a[i].textContent + '\'>' + a[i].textContent + '</a>' + '</pre>');
}


}
}else{ 
    w.document.write('Nenhum link encontrado');
}
```